# How to fix Three.js sprites that are no longer visible?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Still pretty new to JS so I may have missed something obvious...  But I had this project working before and my sprites would float above the map/terrain.

I haven't touched JavaScript in a while let alone three.js... so now I can't figure out what has changed to make the sprites disappear.  I thought it was my textures at first but the terrain and skybox textures are all ok.

I also tried to see if it was an issue with `cube.add(sprite);` by switching it to `scene.add(sprite);` but nothing changed

https://codepen.io/mogiee/pen/eaOvzX

This is what it used to look like:

[image: what it used to look like]

Comment: The codepen you linked has those sprites floating above the map just fine as far as I can tell, what exactly is the difference?

Comment: Yeah, I can second that. The codepen looks exactly like your screenshot. I'm using Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: Confirm. The codepen looks like on the screenshot. Win10 + FF, Chrome.

Comment: man... I was reloading this pen almost all day yesterday and the the sprites never came up on chrome :'( now I check it and it's fine. I guess I should be more patient...

Answer (score 0):

It works how it is, I probably needed to clear my cache or something to make my textures load into the pen.